# How to configure AppDynamics to detect Liferay properly?

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, appdynamics

I want to analyse my Liferay Server with AppDynamics. Is there special configuration to better analyse Liferay specific things or is the only way to check the JSP related execution and not the internal service calls from the JSPs?

System: Liferay 6.2 on Tomcat with a MySQL Database

Answer (score -1):

There are many things you should analyse. It depends on what your LR portal uses most. You may want to analyse web content , user, groups, calnder, theme related services.

Comment: Yes I now, but I want to know if and how it is possible to analyse this with appdynamics.

Comment: This doesn't answer question asked.